# how to find factorial of large no

Tags: java, class, for-loop

I tried to find the factorial of large number ex 1000 by using simple for loop but I didn't get the correct answer whenever I tried I just got `0` as output.

Here is my code

```
class Factorial 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int i, fact = 1;
        int number = 1000;
        for (i = 1; i <= number; i++)
        {
            fact = fact * i;
        }
        System.out.println("Factorial of "+number+" is: " + fact); 
    }
}
```

Output:

> 0

Comment: use bigInteger... the range of int is too low for huge numbers that you are coding for.... here is a link to java docs of bigInteger https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: I think factorial 1000 is bigger as max JS int : 9007199254740991

Comment: `int` and big numbers don´t really play together ;)

Comment: So the output is just `0`? Not `Factorial of 1000 is: 0`?

Comment: @Kayaman the output is Factorial of 1000 is: 0 :)

Comment: Not relevant as solution, but interesting anyway: Why always 0? Imagine we're in decimal system; then we multiply 10, 20, 30, ... With each of them: x(n-1) = `[largeNum]*10^m`, `x(n) = [anotherLN]*10^(m+1)`. If decimal digits are limited and keeping only the least significant ones, we'll reach a point at which we've entirely shifted the `[largeNum]` part out of the range of available digits and we're only calculating `0*something` from now on. Same happens in CPU, just with base 2, so every even factor shifts in a new 0-bit (at least!) from right until all bits are shifted out of the result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large number use BigInteger in the following way

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Factorial {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    BigInteger fact=BigInteger.ONE;
    int number = 1000;
    BigInteger bigNum =new BigInteger(Integer.toString(number));
    for(int i=2;i<=number;i++){
        fact = fact.multiply(bigNum);
        bigNum=bigNum.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    System.out.println("Factorial of " + number + " is: " + fact);
}
}
```

Output :

```
Factorial of 1000 is: 402387260077093773543702433923003985719374864210714632543799910429938512398629020592044208486969404800479988610197196058631666872994808558901323829669944590997424504087073759918823627727188732519779505950995276120874975462497043601418278094646496291056393887437886487337119181045825783647849977012476632889835955735432513185323958463075557409114262417474349347553428646576611667797396668820291207379143853719588249808126867838374559731746136085379534524221586593201928090878297308431392844403281231558611036976801357304216168747609675871348312025478589320767169132448426236131412508780208000261683151027341827977704784635868170164365024153691398281264810213092761244896359928705114964975419909342221566832572080821333186116811553615836546984046708975602900950537616475847728421889679646244945160765353408198901385442487984959953319101723355556602139450399736280750137837615307127761926849034352625200015888535147331611702103968175921510907788019393178114194545257223865541461062892187960223838971476088506276862967146674697562911234082439208160153780889893964518263243671616762179168909779911903754031274622289988005195444414282012187361745992642956581746628302955570299024324153181617210465832036786906117260158783520751516284225540265170483304226143974286933061690897968482590125458327168226458066526769958652682272807075781391858178889652208164348344825993266043367660176999612831860788386150279465955131156552036093988180612138558600301435694527224206344631797460594682573103790084024432438465657245014402821885252470935190620929023136493273497565513958720559654228749774011413346962715422845862377387538230483865688976461927383814900140767310446640259899490222221765904339901886018566526485061799702356193897017860040811889729918311021171229845901641921068884387121855646124960798722908519296819372388642614839657382291123125024186649353143970137428531926649875337218940694281434118520158014123344828015051399694290153483077644569099073152433278288269864602789864321139083506217095002597389863554277196742822248757586765752344220207573630569498825087968928162753848863396909959826280956121450994871701244516461260379029309120889086942028510640182154399457156805941872748998094254742173582401063677404595741785160829230135358081840096996372524230560855903700624271243416909004153690105933983835777939410970027753472000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: i just uses your code and i found the following errors

Comment: have you imported the BigInteger class

Answer (score 0):

Check out these [algorithms](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm): 
And just rewrite the suitable one in java.